# Macro/VBA: How to copy "striked-out" rows to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with certain rows with "striked-out" font. The objective is to cut these rows and paste them into another sheet.

So far, I have the following code, and is not working (EDIT: a new sheet gets created but nothing is cut nor pasted):

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, lrow As Long
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    
    For i = 2 To lrow
      If Cells(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough = True Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Cut
        Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Paste
      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

More like this:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, lrow As Long, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim destRow As Long
    
    Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet   'or something more specific
    lrow = wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'get a reference to the sheet when adding it
    Set wsDest = wsSrc.Parent.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
    destRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    For i = 2 To lrow
        If wsSrc.Cells(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough = True Then
            wsSrc.Rows(i).Cut wsDest.Cells(destRow, 1)
            destRow = destRow + 1 'next paste row
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```